# Why would I use Adobe Edge/Animate?

Tags: css, jquery-animate, wysiwyg, adobe-edge

I tried the latest version of Edge/Animate today, but I'm still wondering what it's main use would be for, and who it is targeted at

In Edge, if I animate a square moving from its original position, to 50px to the right, that right there is 200kb with its default libraries being included

I can do that in CSS3 in less than 1kb, and in jQuery in 92kb

If people are proficient enough with jQuery/CSS3 animation, is there a reason they should ever consider using this product, or is it strictly for people who need a WYSIWYG editor?

I can't find a single example of where Edge does something more efficiently

Please let me know if I've posted this in the wrong spot

Thanks

Comment: This is not a good stackoverflow question. But it's a replacement to flash. You're not going to hand code an entire cartoon episode with css3 and jquery. you're going to use this new tool to use it. it's a very, very smart business decision by adobe.

Comment: So the practical use of this would be for cartoons? What about in regards to every day web design/development? It still doesn't do a lot of things Flash does either, especially in regard to complex timed loops and vector graphics.

Comment: Think of all the terrible things flash was used for. Cartoons, maybe games, who knows. I'm sure the first version of flash didn't do a lot of those things either.

Comment: I'm sure Flash (or FutureSplash) wasn't designed to replace anything of the sort back then. And it did by the way, for the most part.